# How to set a timer for a function and be able to reset it in the middle of the process?

Tags: relay, time

Hello me and my friend have to do an assignment for school but we need some help. We have to make a LED turn on and of with a button and a relay. But when I press the button the LED should be on for 10 minutes and then go off unless we press the button inside those 10 minutes then the LED should turn off. Then repeat this process when we press the button again.

```
const int relay = 6; 
const int button = 5;
int stateold = 1;
int statenew = 0;
int LED = 0;

void setup() 
{   
  pinMode(relay,OUTPUT);   
  pinMode(button,INPUT); 
  time = millis();
} 

void loop() 
{   
  statenew = digitalRead(knop);
  if(stateold==0 && statenew==1){
    if(LED==0){
      digitalWrite(relay,HIGH);
      LED = 1;
      }    
    }
    else{
       digitalWrite(relay,LOW);
        LED = 0;
    }
  }
 stateold=statenew;

}
```

Comment: you need to think about the `LED on for 10 minutes` differently ... it is not one 10 minute action ... it is two very brief actions 10 minutes apart ... do the assignment on paper ... use the kitchen light to represent the LED ... use a clock to time the 10 minutes .... write down everything that you have to do to turn on the light for 10 minutes ... pretend that the button was pressed at some point inside the 10 minute interval ... the steps that you wrote down can be turned into working code

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot to thing in the right direction.

Comment: happy to help .... programming is basically telling a very stupid machine exactly what to do at all times and how to react to every single event of interest

Comment: i forgot to mention, in the pencil and paper excersise in your kitchen, you cannot use your brain to remember anything ... things like starting time and the previous state of the button have to be remembered on paper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is an example of what you described; pressing the button will turn on the LED and it will only turn off if 10 minutes passed or button is pressed again.

Read the comments in the code:

```
#define btn 5
#define rly 6

bool btnState;
bool ledState;
unsigned long timer = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(btn, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(rly, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  btnState = digitalRead(btn); // Read the button status (default is 1)

  if (!btnState) { // If button state == 0 (pressed)
    ledState = !ledState; // Toggle this boolean
    timer = millis(); // and reset the timer
  }

  if (ledState) { // If LED state == 1
    digitalWrite(rly, HIGH); // Turn on the Relay
  } else { // Otherwise turn it off
    digitalWrite(rly, LOW);
  }

  if (ledState && millis() - timer > 600000) { // If 10 minutes passed turn off the relay
    digitalWrite(rly, LOW);
    ledState = !ledState;
  }
}
```

You should also de-bounce the button and you may want to turn on/off the LED when button is pressed **and** released, not just when it's pressed.

Comment: Thank you very much you help us a lot and it works now. Only in the last if statement you forgot a ledState = !ledState.

Comment: @daan YW, yep it should toggle the `ledState` in timer statement.